# Can't figure out MySQL statement which will return needed result

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

- questions
- answers
- qa_assoc which standing for `question id<->answer id` relationship

What I'm trying to do is following: Select all questions, if any question has answer select answer too.

```
SELECT q.id, q.content, a.id, a.content, a.dt 
        FROM questions q 
        JOIN qa_assoc qaa ON qaa.qid=q.id
        JOIN answers a ON a.id=qaa.aid
        WHERE q.course_id=? AND q.lesson_id=? AND a.user_id=?
```

But this sql only selects the questions which have an answer. How can I achieve my idea? any suggestions? thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have **a** in your `WHERE` if you want rows without **a**, moved it to the `ON` part

```
SELECT q.id, q.content, a.id, a.content, a.dt 
FROM questions q 
LEFT JOIN qa_assoc qaa ON (qaa.qid=q.id)
LEFT JOIN answers a ON (a.id=qaa.aid  AND a.user_id=?)
WHERE q.course_id=? AND q.lesson_id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inner / outer / left join?
Have a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html